# convert .py program to c language using cython

Tags: python, c, cython

Trying to convert .py code to c language. (I took sample `hello world.py` program ) And I compiled using below.

```
cython --embed -o hello_world.c hello_world.py
```

Now i have to make this as executable

```
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.3m -o hello hello.c -lpython3.3m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

I am not understanding how I can use above command and `hello.c` is in `/root/cythonrnd`. If I run this I am getting the below error:

```
hello.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
#include "pyconfig.h"
^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Does `/usr/include/python3.3m` exist on your system?

Comment: no what is the solution ?

Comment: kindly let me know how can i execute ?

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring a python version that doesn't exist on your system, or just you didn't installed the developer files.

It seems that you have Linux, so check that you have installed also the correct `python*-dev` package.

In general, you should never include the path explicitly: use the output of

```
pkg-config --cflags python3
pkg-config --libs python3
```

in your build scripts, or in your gcc command line.
Replace `python3` with `python` for the normal system Python version, or specify a python version e.g. `python3.6`.